# Can Cocoa Touch UI objects be serialized, transmitted over a network, and reconstituted on a client?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, serialization

I've been working on and off with a team that's developing an iPhone app. Like a lot of other developers new to Cocoa Touch, we decided to create a hybrid Cocoa-Web app which was essentially a few buttons controlling some UIWebViews -- partly to (a) leverage existing web development expertise, partly because of (b) the advantage in pushing out changes (change stuff on the server, no need to push out a new version of the app), and partly because (c) the app is inherently focused on pulling data from the network anyway.

We've reached a point, however, where this hybrid approach looks like it's having notable costs against polish and performance. We're working on this problem, but I think we've all started to wonder if a more purely Cocoa client might not be a better move.

The big question is -- is there an arrangement under Cocoa where we can keep advantage (b)? Is there some way to serialize Cocoa Touch UI objects in such a way that they can be transmitted over the network and reconstituted for display on a client? If so, when serialized, are they lightweight enough for this to be practical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting idea. You can serialize anything that implements the NSCoding protocol—that's what it's for—so pretty much anything you can put into a XIB should allow you to archive it. You might even be able to take advantage of `UIViewController`'s `initWithNibName:bundle:`; your app could download and expand a bundle containing a nib into its documents directory, then load that with the `UIViewController` method and `NSBundle +bundleWithPath:`. I think you might even be okay with the SDK's terms—they forbid loading "plugin" code, but XIBs don't contain anything executable.

For more information, check out the [Archives and Serializations Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html).

Answer (score 1):

an .xib file is a serialized representation of Objective-C objects.  You can archive and unarchive objects the same way that IB does.  See the docs for NSKeyedArchiver and related subjects.